# .map() parameter is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array with data, and I want to compare the data with the event.target.value 
When it is the same value, I want it to get more information about data that is in that position of the array.

it says character is not defined, and I guess it's a scoping problem but i don't know how to fix it.

The console.log(character.mass, character.height) is for testing purposes.

```
handleClick(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        const CharacterDataArray = this.props.CharacterData.results
        console.log(CharacterDataArray)

        if(CharacterDataArray.map(character => character.name === event.target.value)) {
            console.log(character.mass, character.height)
        }
        this.setState({
            CharacterName: event.target.value
        })
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the result of console.log(CharacterDataArray)

Comment: Why are you using the result of `map` as a condition in your if-statement? Are you checking for an empty array?

Comment: `character` is used only inside `map()`. You try to console.log it in `if` statement. That's why it is undefined there.

Comment: @byxor I'm doing it because I want to return the this.state, but don't know if it is the right way? Would you suggest a forEach()?

Comment: I used the solution from @sandrooco in the post below and it turns out the arrow function in optional. Thanks for the help!

Comment: just add .langht at the and of if

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the arrow function to resolve the scop issue like

```
 handleClick =(event)=>{
  // your code goes here 
}
```

or you can bind the click event in the constructor like

```
constructor () {
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `character` is only defined in the `map`'s callback function.

Try this instead:

```
// Look through all characters and return it if the name matches
const matchingChar = CharacterDataArray.find(character => character.name === event.target.value)

// Log if a match has been found
if (matchingChar) {
    console.log(matchingChar.mass, matchingChar.height);
}
```

Comment: This works! @sandrooco, the arrow function is optional, works both ways. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `.map` you can use `.some` for reference, you can go to this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: and if your `this.props` cannot be reachable you must be changed to `arrow function` eg: `handleClick = () => {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find` method to find a character where the `character.name` equals the `event.target.value`.

```
 const  hasValue =  CharacterDataArray.find(character => character.name === event.target.value)

   if(hasValue) {

 // write your logic
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use arrow function because inside arrow function you can acess "this" and second thing you need to check also array is not empty

```
    handleClick  = (event) => {

        event.preventDefault();

        if(this.props.CharacterData.results && this.props.CharacterData.results.length > 0) {

     if(this.props.CharacterData.results.map(character => character.name === event.target.value)) {
            console.log(character.mass, character.height)
        }
        this.setState({
            CharacterName: event.target.value
        })

     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:-

```
CharacterDataArray.map((character) => {  
 if (character.name === event.target.value)) 
  { 
   console.log(character.mass, character.height)
  }
 })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
async handleClick(event){
await event.preventDefault();
let CharacterDataArray = this.props.CharacterData.results;
console.log(CharacterDataArray);
let result=CharacterDataArray.filter(character=>character.name === event.target.value);
    console.log(result.mass, result.height);
}
```

Comment: `preventDefault()` doesn't return any promise? The other code will throw an error... (`result` is an array, not an object).